# System DMV's missing from SQL Server 2017 master.dacpac in SSDT 2015

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I have Ola Hallengren's excellent Maintenance Solution scripts incorporated in to a DBA tools database project.  This is maintained using SSDT 2015 with a target platform of SQL Server 2012.  The project includes references to the built-in system databases master & msdb.  The project builds successfully.

Ola has recently [updated](https://ola.hallengren.com/versions.html) his scripts and they now include references to new SQL Server 2017 DMV's, so incorporating the updated scripts into my database project generated unresolved reference errors for the new DMV's.

```
SQL71502: Procedure: [dbo].[DatabaseBackup] has an unresolved reference to object [sys].[dm_os_host_info]
SQL71502: Procedure: [dbo].[DatabaseBackup] has an unresolved reference to object [sys].[dm_db_log_stats]
```

Although I don't have SQL Server 2017 installed anywhere, I tried updating the target platform to SQL Server 2017 and then deleting and recreating the master database reference (i.e. to update the master.dacpac to the SQL Server 2017 version), but that did not remove the build errors.

The file path for the referenced dacpac is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\140\SqlSchemas\master.dacpac
```

When I check the dacpac, the new DMV's [sys].[dm_os_host_info] and [sys].[dm_db_log_stats] aren't in there.

I reached out on Slack yesterday and Peter Schott referred to me to an excellent blog post he'd written regarding how to update the master.dacpac ([link](https://schottsql.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/ssdt-adding-logins-for-execute-as/)).  The theory being to grab the missing DMV's and add them to the master.dacpac myself.  I'd have to spin up a test machine and install SQL Server 2017 to do this, but it's feasible as a workaround.

However, it feels like something I shouldn't have to do.  After all, these are system DMV's missing from the master.dacpac, rather than adding my own code to the master database.

So, I guess my questions are:

1. Is this an issue with my local SSDT install, or a general issue with system DMV's missing from the dacpac that SSDT installs?
2. How do I get an updated (and signed) master.dacpac without hacking it myself?

Comment: This is a general issue. Installing the latest SSDT (15.6.0) from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt) gives you a `master.dacpac` with a `model.xml` that's missing these DMVs, and furthermore has a suggestive date of 2016-10-16 (which is also the release date of SQL Server 2017 CTP1, although that doesn't necessarily mean there were no updates since then). The page suggests the [forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=ssdt) to contact the team.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert, I've raised it on the MSDN forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't have a resolution to the original issue (system DMV's missing from the master.dacpac), I do have answers to the two questions I originally posed.

Yes, this is a general issue with the master.dacpac that comes with SSDT.  And no, there does not appear to be any way to get an updated master.dacpac without hacking it yourself using the workaround detailed previously.

I've now raised an item on [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/34118779-provide-a-way-to-update-ssdt-system-database-refer), requesting a method for updating the system database DACPACs in SSDT. 
 Please consider voting for it if you have a chance.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I did for this was

1. add an additional SSDT project (e.g. "master_expanded")
2. script out some dummy items for the missing references (e.g. a dummy table with the following columns: `select * from sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('select * from  [sys].[dm_os_host_info]', default, default);`
3. add master_expanded as a database reference from the original project ("same database, same server") -- now the original project can find sys.dm_os_host_info

Note that the dummy schema objects have to be excluded from the actual deployment.  We use a schema compare file (scmp) so we just have these objects excluded.